# Software for streaming video

Tags: streaming, camera

My use is i want to stream 4 usb webcams connected to orange pi plus 2e which is connected to the network via gigabit ethernet, my need is to have the least lag possible.

What choice of software and webcam can meet the requirement.
I chose the orange pi because ,
1) has gigabit ethernet Native 
2) has 4 usb 2.0 ports without hubs 
if there is a better suited board please suggest it along with software.

Edit: i am not asking about a webcam just about the best software used to lower the lag as much as possible and if there is any camera that needs to go with it.

Comment: You cannot ask here about webcams - this is a software forum. Where do you want to straem to? Please [edit] your question

Comment: @JanDoggen: this is not a forum ;-)